# convert html table to word document or editable pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, ms-word

I have been using [jquery datatable](https://www.datatables.net/) and [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF), for exporting [html table to pdf](http://jsfiddle.net/NishitDhakar/ugD5L/) using codes like

```
pdf.fromHTML(
    source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
    margins.left, // x coord
    margins.top, { // y coord
        'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    }
```

Is there a javascript library to export the html table to **word document**(preferred) or **editable** pdf?

Comment: The author of jsPdf made https://github.com/MrRio/DOCX.js or  could you do it serverside?

Comment: thanks for the lead, I am looking for a client side solution for document generation

Comment: https://github.com/MrRio/DOCX.js is client side

Comment: sure, checking it now :)

Comment: @pce Can you post it as answer, so that I can accept it as answer?
I used DOCX generator and its working fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author of jsPdf made a document generator for Microsoft Word documents in Pure client-side JavaScript called [DOCX.js](http://github.com/MrRio/DOCX.js) and recommends the usage of Stephen Hardy's [DOCX.js](https://github.com/stephen-hardy/DOCX.js).

DOCX.js depends on [JSZip](http://stuk.github.io/jszip//) and supports the writing of bold, italic, underline, strikethrough, subscript, superscript, font sizes, font color, highlights, and horizontal alignment. For reading, it supports all of the above plus embedded PNGs. Support for tables and lists (bulleted and numbered) will likely come in the future, but is not currently present.

Demo-Usage of [ZerdaH's Fork](https://github.com/ZerdaH/DOCX.js):

```
var docDOM = document.getElementById('example');

var docObject = docx.export(docDOM, // required DOM Object
{
    creator: "Creator", // optional String
    lastModifiedBy: "Last person to modify", // optional String
    created: new Date(), // optional Date Object
    modified: new Date() // optional Date Object
});

var link = document.createElement('a');
link.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Download Link Text"));
link.title = "Download Title";
link.download = "FilenameHere.docx";
link.href = docObject.href();
document.getElementById("example").appendChild(link);
```