# Export table to MS-Word

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]

```
function export2Word() {

    var html, link, blob, url, css;

    css = (
               '<style>  table {   border-collapse: collapse;  border-style:none;  } .tables td,th{border:1px solid black;}' +
               //'@page WordSection1{size: 841.95pt 595.35pt;mso-page-orientation: landscape;}' +
               //'div.WordSection1 {page: WordSection1;} ' +
               '</style>'
             );

     html = document.getElementById("tblPrint").outerHTML;
     blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', css + html], {
                 type: 'application/msword'
             });
     url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
     link = document.createElement('A');
     link.href = url;
     link.download = 'Document';  // default name without extension 
     document.body.appendChild(link);
     if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) 
         navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, 'Document.doc'); // IE10-11
     else link.click();  // other browsers
         document.body.removeChild(link);
};
```

I want to export table to MS-Word when I tried then not showing any table structure just showing data

and I used page break for new rollno using like `<div style="page-break-after:always;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>` this also not working

what is wrong in my code? and what to do for page break in ms-word?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

please try this will work

[export html table as word file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330859/export-html-table-as-word-file-and-change-file-orientation)

or

```
var docDOM = document.getElementById('example');

var docObject = docx.export(docDOM, // required DOM Object
{
creator: "Creator", // optional String
lastModifiedBy: "Last person to modify", // optional String
created: new Date(), // optional Date Object
modified: new Date() // optional Date Object
});

var link = document.createElement('a');
link.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Download Link Text"));
link.title = "Download Title";
link.download = "FilenameHere.docx";
link.href = docObject.href();
document.getElementById("example").appendChild(link);
```

[convert html table to word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983922/convert-html-table-to-word-document-or-editable-pdf)

Comment: I tried both it export it properly no issue with that but table structure not showing only content export